# Error: Call to a member function hashName() on null

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Task: Upload image on s3 server

The code functioning properly on my local system and the file in saving properly on s3 server but when I push this code on server it gives me the hashName error.

`Error: Call to a member function hashName() on null in file /var/www/html/doctring-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php on line 240`

Code for Image Helper

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class UserHelper
{
    public static function uploadImage($image)
    {
        try {
            if (count(explode("data:image/", $image)) > 1) {

                $fileName = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
                $image = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '',$image));
                Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $image, 'public');

                return $fileName;
            }

            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Api Controller

```
 public function uploadPrescription(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'patient_id' => 'required',
            'appointment_id' => 'required',
            'prescription' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        $input = $request->all();

        $status_check = Appointment::where('id','=',$input['appointment_id'])->first();
        if($status_check->status == 'OnGoing'){

            //upload prescription(image in base64) to s3 bucket
            if($request->has('prescription'))
            {
                $imageName = UserHelper::uploadImage($request->prescription);

                $input['image_url'] = $imageName;
            }

            $data=[
                'patient_id' => $input['patient_id'],
                'appointment_id' => $input['appointment_id'],
                'prescription'=>  $imageName
            ];

            //Uploading Prescription only one record
//            $profile = Prescriptions::updateOrCreate(Arr::except($data, 'prescription'), $data);

            $profile = Prescriptions::updateOrCreate($data);
            return response()->json(['message' => "Prescription Uploaded", 'profile'=> $profile, 'error'=> 0, 'status'=> 1 ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['message' => "Prescription Uploading Failed", 'error'=> 1, 'status'=> 0 ]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At line 240 of `Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter` as reported by your error, there is this line:

```
return $this->putFileAs($path, $file, $file->hashName(), $options);
```

This means that $file is null when you are trying to upload it.
In your question you say that in local environment you don't have this problem, so you should check in the code that precede this, what is causing the problem on the production server environment.

Hope this helps